# ASP.NET Web API correct way to have two types of ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Web API application which has two types of users — clients and drivers. Currently, I have methods in the client and driver controller for registering clients and drivers. I realised the correct way to do this is through the built-in authentication system via the `ApplicationUser` class. Basically, the whole thing is confusing me because for both of the user types I have different fields. Anyway, I have come up with two possible solutions, however, both of them don't sound like the correct way to achieve my goal.

1) Inherit from `ApplicationUser`

ApplicationUser.cs

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Client.cs

```
public class Client : ApplicationUser
{
}
```

Driver.cs

```
public class Driver: ApplicationUser
{
    private ICollection<Country> countriesOfOperation;

    public Driver()
    {
        this.countriesOfOperation = new HashSet<Country>();
    }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string AboutMe { get; set; }

    public Genders Gender { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Country> CountriesOfOperation
    {
        get { return this.countriesOfOperation; }
        set { this.countriesOfOperation = value; }
    }
}
```

This means that I have to create register methods into the AccountController like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Clients/register")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RegisterClient(ClientRegisterBindingModel model)
{
    var user = new Client()
    {
        UserName = model.Email,
        Email = model.Email,
        RegistrationDate = DateTime.Now
    };

    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        return GetErrorResult(result);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Same thing goes for the driver class. Surely, the inheritance reuses stuff like UserName, Email, PasswordHash etc., but it also means that I have to create methods like the register one for every type of user I add. Which makes the account management pain in the ass.

2) Keeping clients and drivers in separate tables by having a field that references an `ApplicationUser`

```
public class Client
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser Account { get; set; }
}
```

This seems a bit better, but to access the username of a client I have to do something like `clientInstance.Account.UserName`, which still doesn't seem elegant enough.

I'm pretty new to the technology and I haven't explored all of its features, so I'm likely missing something fairly obvious. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep Clients and Drivers in the same table just have different accountId for them perhaps have a column called `Group` and manually create them having all clients as Group 1 and all Drivers as Group 2

Comment: @MethodMan, wouldn't keeping them in the same table leave too much unused columns? For example, the driver class has 3-4 fields that the client doesn't have, which means that they will have to be NULL for a client row.

Comment: it would be really nice to see an example of how your database is laid out , you could use 2 tables and construct a Joined query I think that you're making approach harder than it needs to be.. there are many ways to skin this cat

Comment: @arnaudoff I think better way is to separate two types of users by assigning them appropriate Roles.

Comment: What abiut role based authentication like @AndriiTsok said?

Comment: @AndriiTsok, the problem is that the driver and the client have the same role — user. I think what you are suggesting might work for administrator/user or similar, unless of course there is a way to map a role to a certain model, then that would be the perfect solution. Please elaborate on how would I implement my case using roles.

Comment: @arnaudoff but you can use multiple roles for your users. For example someone can be User and Drive  and someone else User and Client. This approach will help you to keep your code clean and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a single table for all types of users. User registration will be the same for all. When a new user is created you'll add additional details there.

```
Schema:
int ID
int UserType
nvarchar Details
etc...

Entity:
public class User
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public int UserType {get;set;}
   public string Email{get;set;}
   public string Password{get;set;}
   public string Details {get;set;}
}
```

During registration they get handled the same. When a new user is created is where you'll add various details.

```
//driver
var user = new User()
{
    Details = {
       TruckID = 5,
       SomeOtherDetails = "Whatever"
    }.ToJson() //fake extention method, just convert to jsons string
};

//client
var user = new User()
{
    Details = {
       ClientNumber = 44
    }.ToJson() 
};
```

If these need to be worked with later just get the user then deserialize the details out to various types based on the user type.

```
var user = GetSomeuser(1);
var truckID = user.Details.FromJson<DriveDetails>().TruckID; //fake extension method to deserialize json string back to object

public class DriverDetails
{
   pubic int TruckID...
   public string SomeOtherDetails...
}
```

Comment: The first part of the answer is to show you how you "could" handle it but it's not advised. Users should just be users and they register the same way. If a certain kind of user needs different details just stores them like a document database would and deserialize them back out based on what type of user it is.

Comment: Basically, your idea is to have a separate table for the additional details and have a foreign key to it? For example, I having the user Foo with the default account properties as an ApplicationUser, but also having column for the type of the ApplicationUser and another column that is a foreign key to a table containing the additional columns I need for the particular type of user?

Comment: Well that was one way but the preferred way would be to just have a single table. All additional details would go into a json string into that field.

Comment: I've updated the answer to try and better demonstrate this.

Comment: Any details not needed to query to find the row you are looking for can just be stored together in a json string and parsed back out when needed.

Comment: Good point, but how would searching in the details work? How would I implement relations between a property of the details and another column, i.e a foreign key to a totally different table? I think mixing relational and NoSQL is inevitably going to lead to a mess.

Comment: The idea behind it is it doesn't need to be relational. Just store the data you don't need at the table level to query on to find the record and everything else gets stored together in the structure you choose.